# Not able to update SimpleForm TextInput value in react-admin

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-admin

```
<SimpleForm
label="resources.xyz"
{...props}

<TextInput
source="latitude"
label="resources.latitude"
defaultValue={
gpsLocation?.capturedLocation?.latitude || props?.record?.latitude
}
value={
gpsLocation?.capturedLocation?.latitude || props?.record?.latitude
}
/>......
```

In this the gpsLocation?.capturedLocation?.latitude and longitude is change when we capturing the location by a separate function but the textInput value is not going when we submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

`props.record` is probably undefined if you're in an `<Edit>` component. Besides, you should not use the record latitude in the default value. React-admin takes care of that when the record is loaded. Finally, react-admin's TextInput is a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), so you should not set the `value` yourself.

This should work:

```
<TextInput
    source="latitude"
    label="resources.latitude"
    defaultValue={gpsLocation?.capturedLocation?.latitude}
/>
```

Comment: Hi Francois Zaninotto,
Thank you for reply.

But when we are using defaultValue and updating this variable   (gpsLocation?.capturedLocation?.latitude) value then it is not reflecting in form. While in  the value={gpsLocation?.capturedLocation?.latitude}  it updated in the form but does not go the updated value with form while saving. We are trying to update value by props (gpsLocation?.capturedLocation?.latitude) update by calling a function through another button.

Comment: the defaultValue is used on mount only. Any change to it after mount is ignored. That's the way react-final-form works. If you want to change the value of a record programmatically, use react-final-form's `useForm` to grab the form instance, then call `form.change('latitude', gpsLocation?.capturedLocation?.latitude)` (see https://final-form.org/docs/final-form/types/FormApi#change for details)